# haproxy able to add client ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

Is it possible to use haproxy to add a ssl client certificate before sending requests to the backend server ?

Use case:

App1 -> haproxyOut -> internet -> haproxyIn -> App2

Is haproxyOut able to add client certificate that could be validate by haproxyIn ?

I'd like haproxyOut to initiate the ssl connection with a client certificate and haproxyIn to terminate the ssl connection

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a solution:

I just have to add the pem file of the client certificate on the server line of the backend of haproxyOut.

The doc say (backend server section):

crt

It designates a PEM file from which to load both a certificate and the
associated private key. This file can be built by concatenating both PEM
files into one. This certificate will be sent if the server send a client
certificate request.